# Scoring a Probability Distribution

Tags: statistics

Say I have model that gives me a probability distribution describing how player X might perform against opponents/team Y (think Fantasy Sports teams).  Rather than simply taking the average, is there a more intelligent method of player selection when choosing an optimal team?  For example, players with unusual skewness/kurtosis might present higher risk factors.

Comment: [stats.se] is the site for statistics.